# Proving $\left|\left|\vec{w}\right|\right|^2 \ge \sum_{j=1}^n\left|\langle\vec{w},\vec{u}_j\rangle\right|^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Proving $\left|\left|\vec{w}\right|\right|^2 \ge \sum_{j=1}^n\left|\langle\vec{w},\vec{u}_j\rangle\right|^2$.

$\vec{u}_1,...,\vec{u}_j$ is a set of orthonormal vectors in an inner product space $V$. $\vec{w}\in V$

I'm trying to understand this before my test tomorrow morning. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Do you understand the question?  Did you have an approach in mind?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Also, in the future: please refrain from putting your question only in the title; the body of your post should be understandable on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly wrong. If $u_1,\cdots,u_n$ is an orthonormal basis of the vector space $V$ then for any vector $w\in V$ you can write
$$w=c_1u_1+\cdots+c_nu_n$$
Then $\langle w,u_j\rangle=c_j$. Hence
$$w=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle w,u_i\rangle u_i$$
Then 
$$||w||^2=\langle w,w\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle w,u_i\rangle u_i,w\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle w,u_i\rangle\langle u_i,w\rangle$$
Hence proved.

Comment: In what way is the question wrong?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom. I think he is referring to the fact that the orthonormal basis should read $\{\boldsymbol{u}_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$, instead of $\{\boldsymbol{u}_{j}\}_{j=1}^{j}$

Comment: But the question never said that the set was a basis of $V$. In fact, I suspect that it is intended **not** to be, hence the inequality as opposed to equality.

Comment: The answer makes sense and seems simple to update to cover the situation where $u_1,...,u_j$ is not a basis for $W$ but simply a set in $W$.